# Webgl vertexAttribPointer: index out of range

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

I'm trying to pass uv buffer as well as the normal buffer in webgl. But for some reason I get this warning `vertexAttribPointer: index out of range` when passing values. I don't get what I m doing wrong since the uv array seems to be good, same goes for the normals.

It seems like the errors only occured with normal and uv not with position.

`enableVertexAttribArray: index out of range`

`vertexAttribPointer: index out of range`

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

const vsSource = `
    attribute vec4 position;
    attribute vec2 uv;
    attribute vec3 normal;
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    void main(void) {
      gl_Position = position;
    }
  `;

const fsSource = `  
    precision mediump float;
    varying vec4 vColor;
    void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);
    }
  `;

// Shader setup

let vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vsSource);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    var log = gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);
    throw "Shader compilation failed\n\n" + log + "\n\n";
}

var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fsSource);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    var log = gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader);
    throw "Shader compilation failed\n\n" + log + "\n\n";
}

let program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);

gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.validateProgram(program);

if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    var log = gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
    throw "Program link failed\n\n" + log;
}

gl.useProgram(program);

let modelViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "modelViewMatrix");

let model = mat4.create();

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrix, false, model);

var vertices = new Float32Array([
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5,
    -0.5
]);

var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let position = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");

gl.vertexAttribPointer(position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(position);

var uvBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0
    ]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
);

let uv = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "uv");

gl.vertexAttribPointer(uv, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(uv);

var normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        -1
    ]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
);

let normal = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "normal");

gl.vertexAttribPointer(normal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(normal);

var indices = new Uint16Array([
    0,
    2,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    1,
    4,
    6,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    5,
    8,
    10,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    9,
    12,
    14,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    13,
    16,
    18,
    17,
    18,
    19,
    17,
    20,
    22,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    21
]);

var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shaders are not using `uv` or `normal` so your driver is optimizing out those attributes. In that case `gl.getAttribLocation` returns -1 for location (-1 = attribute by this name does not exist). -1 is out of range. Valid values are 0 to `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS) - 1`

In other words you need check the location of your attributes and if they don't exist, don't set them up.

This is one reason why it's good to [write some helper functions for WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-less-code-more-fun.html) to kind of handle these issues for you so as you modify your shaders your code doesn't break.